# Alamofire post request returning "ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"

Tags: ios, swift, asp.net-web-api, alamofire

Using swift 4, I am doing a post request to a web api. The api has correct JSON data but whenever i call it is returning the following response:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

My code is:

```
let urlString = "XXXXXXXXXX/ArticlesByListofIds"
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["ids": "160, 145"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseString { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success(let responseString1):
            print("the response is: \(responseString1)")
        break

        case .failure(let error):
            print("The error is: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I see two things happening. First, the API seems to respond with XML rather than JSON, so probably your request is not what you intended it to be. Second, there seems to be an issue with character encoding. This could be anything; maybe a fault in the server configuration, maybe you are decoding the file incorrectly.